# Word for the action of flipping the pages of a book (such as when viewing flip book animation)?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Would like to know if there is any terminology for the action/activity/motion of flipping the pages of a book as one would do when viewing the animation of a flip book, scanning top corner of book to locate a numbered page, or looking for a titled section in the text?

*[I am working on a document describing various ways the reader uses there hands to hold and interact with a physical book and the terms such as flipping or flicking don't seem appropriate for the precise controlled action I'm trying to refer to]*

Comment: You flip through a flip book. That's the terminology used in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_book) and most other places. It's why it's called a flip book.

Comment: But you also flip through a magazine [a more common usage] and that uses a very different motion.

Comment: *Anko [**fanned** through](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fanned+through+the+book+of%22) the book of empty pages. He chuckled and fanned through the book again, and something caught his eye. “Wait! Something's written on one of the pages.” Holding his breath, he **flipped** the pages back and forth until he...* That's *both* of the most common terms used in the same paragraph. You can decide for yourself whether they're actually intended to convey [slightly?] different meanings there, but personally I don't think so.

Answer (score 5):

We often use the word ["riffle"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riffle) (or sometimes ["riff"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riff)) for that action:

> riffle verb
>
> intransitive verb
> 2: to flip cursorily : THUMB
> // *riffle* through the catalog
>
> transitive verb
> 2a: to leaf through hastily
> specifically : to leaf by sliding a thumb along the edge of the leaves
> // *riffle* a stack of paper

> riff verb
>
> : riffle, skim
> // *riff* pages