# Word for manipulating paper notes in hand

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that would describe the action of holding a large number of paper notes in one hand and using the thumb or other fingers of the other hand to "flick through" them. The context is a character playing with money.

The only word that came to mind is "flick" but I don't think that's quite right.

Comment: Related: [Word for the action of flipping the pages of a book (such as when viewing flip book animation)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585881/word-for-the-action-of-flipping-the-pages-of-a-book-such-as-when-viewing-flip-b/585882#585882)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Riffle** (v.)

> To flick through (papers, books, etc.); to thumb (a block of paper, a
> book, etc.), releasing the leaves in (usually rapid) succession.
>
> **1977**   G. Durrell *Golden Bats & Pink Pigeons* iv. 87   He took my passport and **riffled** it..like an expert card sharper.
>
> **2000**   S. King *On Writing* 244   Most magazine editors can tell how long a story is just by looking at the print and **riffling** the
> pages. [OED]

---

> He **riffled** the bills over with his thumb and finally extracted one
> which he held out to Luther; it was a two. [Mary Watts; *Luther
> Nichols*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Luther_Nichols/g3AHAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=he%20riffled%20the%20bills&pg=PA105&printsec=frontcover) (1923)

> He **riffled** through the stack of bills, holding the stack in my line of
> vision but not too close—I was meant to see what he was doing. He
> **riffled**, then looked up at me, questioning, and then **riffled** again. “Well?" [Simon Cann; *Bag Man*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bag_Man/o8CfDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=he%20riffled%20the%20bills&pg=PT17&printsec=frontcover)  (2016)

> He **riffled** the bills, saw they were in a series; the last bill was
> F20011936E. [Gerald Browne; *Green Ice*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Green_Ice/uxVhBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=he%20riffled%20the%20bills&pg=PT27&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

Answer (score 2):

***riffle*** is [most commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riffled%20the%20cards%2Cruffled%20the%20cards&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) with *playing **cards** in a **deck...***

[image]

...but that preference is [nowhere near as strong](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riffled%20the%20pages%2Cruffled%20the%20pages&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) with ***pages** in a **book...***

[image]

And when it comes to *(loose) **sheets*** [the preference actually reverses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riffled%20the%20sheets%2Cruffled%20the%20sheets&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), to favour ***ruffled*** over ***riffled...***

[image]

...and that preference is [even more marked](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riffled%20the%20leaves%2Cruffled%20the%20leaves&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) when it comes to more loosely connected ***leaves*** (whether that's actual foliage, or the contents of a [loose-leaf binder](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/loose-leaf-binder) taken out ready to be referred to while delivering a talk)...

[image]

---

TL;DR: We ***riffle*** (logically or physically) tightly-connected cards in a deck or pages in a book. But we ***ruffle*** loose sheets of paper.

It's probably also worth noting that ***riffling*** is usually a very precise / dexterous action, typified by a "card-sharp" who divides a deck in two, then ["riffles" the two halves together to shuffle the deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling). Idly "ruffling" some loose sheets of paper is nowhere near such a precise action.

Answer (score 0):

Two words come to mind:

**to riffle**

As in "The woman riffled through the bundle."

This is closer to "going through" though. I imagine you are after something like

**to rake**

As in "The woman raked her finger across the edge of the bundle."

Comment: You should look up in a dictionary before you post an answer, and also quote what you find. [Rake](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rake) in this context means to touch lightly or scrape, not to flick or manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase you're looking for is **flip through**.

For an exact example of the behavior you're describing see this stock footage of a [Businessman Flipping Through the Bills in a Bundle of Money](https://videohive.net/item/businessman-flipping-through-the-bills-in-a-bundle-of-money-rich-man-holding-a-stack-of-100-us/33188135) and [Hands flipping through a stack of US dollar bills](https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-24276305-hands-flipping-through-stack-us-dollar-bills) (which both demonstrate the word in use too).